# Rails before_filter different arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, before-filter

I have controller actions which all use one method but with different arguments.
Can I refactor this somehow to use `before_filter`?

```
  def usd_cash
    transaction_currency("USD cash")
  end

  def usd_bank
    transaction_currency("USD bank")
  end

  def rub_bank
    transaction_currency("RUB bank")
  end

  private

  def transaction_currency(currency)
    @transactions = Transaction.where(location: "#{currency}")
  end
```

Comment: looks good as is. Notice you could just have `location: currency`

Comment: Yes, true. 
I'm just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: yes you could using `params[:action]` but feels hacky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some metaprogramming, but this would not be as readable as what you currently have:

```
%i(
  usd_cash
  usd_bank
  rub_bank
).each do |method|
  define_method method do
    transaction_currency(method.to_s.split('_').instance_eval {first.upcase + ' ' + last})
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that's it. 
Really looks less readable, so I'm not gonna use it but now I know that this is theoretically possible

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.You can call `usd_type` like `before_filter { usd_type("RUB bank")}`

I supposed here you do this before filter, You can change with your own requirement.

```
def usd_type(type)
  transaction_currency(type)
end

private

def transaction_currency(currency)
  @transactions = Transaction.where(location: "#{currency}")
end
```